# Django upgrade from 1.2.5 to 1.3 error in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, upgrade, django-1.3

I am attempting to upgrade a website running django 1.2.5 to 1.3
The only error I have encountered so far is in the admin part of the site:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_path'
```

which I think is from somewhere in this code:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EventArtistsInline, EventGalleryInline, EventRelatedObjectInline, EventPriceInline, SeriesPassInline, EventsInSeriesInline, ]
    save_as = True
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("prefix", "title", "suffix")}
    list_filter = ('start_date', 'is_series')
    search_fields = ['title', 'description', 'intro',]

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.list_display_links = ['title']
            self.list_display= ['title', 'status', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'hide_artists', 'featured', 'is_series', 'tickets_sold', 'tickets_remaining', 'sold_out']
            self.list_editable = ['featured', 'status', 'hide_artists', 'is_series','sold_out',]
        else:
            self.list_display_links = ['']
            self.list_display= ['title', 'status', 'start_date', 'tickets_sold', 'tickets_remaining', 'sold_out']
            self.list_editable = ['status']
        return super(EventAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    class Media:
        js = [
            settings.MEDIA_URL+'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            settings.MEDIA_URL+"filebrowser/js/TinyMCEAdmin.js",
        ]
```

How can I fix this?

Full stack trace below:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://example.com/admin/events/event/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['grappelli',
 'admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.menu',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'filebrowser',
 'galleries',
 'products',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'kp.applications.seasonal_dates',
 'kp.utils',
 'people',
 'pages',
 'archive',
 'locations',
 'partners',
 'campaigns',
 'events',
 'memberships',
 'registration',
 'captcha',
 'session_cart',
 'colours',
 'order',
 'genres',
 'mamona',
 'musicshop',
 'mamona.backends.stripe',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'email_usernames',
 'profiles',
 'landing_pages',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'emailmgr',
 'filebrowser']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'session_cart.middleware.CartMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  307.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  197.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "./events/admin.py" in changelist_view
  55.         return super(EventAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  28.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  24.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1056.                 self.list_select_related, self.list_per_page, self.list_editable, self)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in __init__
  67.         self.filter_specs, self.has_filters = self.get_filters(request)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in get_filters
  77.                                          field_path=filter_name)
File "/var/projects/example.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filterspecs.py" in create
  39.                                field_path=field_path)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/events/event/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_path'
```

Comment: What makes you think the error originates in that class? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @jstlaurent Yes, this is in the middle of the traceback: `./events/admin.py in changelist_view

            return super(EventAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)`

Comment: well you should have posted the full stacktrace. Anyway why are you upgrading to a version of django that became obsolote about 5 years ago?

Comment: @e4c5 sorry, I've just amended the original post to include the full stack trace. I did attempt to skip a few versions with the upgrade but found a lot more errors, so I am attempting this smaller upgrade first.

Comment: surprisingly none of your code shows up in it. The usual practice to solve this sort of problem is to comment out all the code in your admin and add it back bit by bit to see what exactly causes the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what is wrong here.

The error is triggered in a file called `filterspecs.py`. I suspect that it might be because you have a list filter `is_series` that is not included in the `self.list_display`.

Try to comment out the `list_filter` line, and see if that changes anything.

```
list_filter = ('start_date', 'is_series')
self.list_display= ['title', 'status', 'start_date', 'tickets_sold', 
                    'tickets_remaining', 'sold_out']
```

It could also be some bug that was fixed in a later version of django. Since having `admin.py` files are optional, you could just delete or rename them during the upgrade process until you have fixed other problems. This error might be caused by a problem that was fixed in a later version of django.

Comment: thanks, removing the `list_filter` line fixes it. Later versions have LOTS of problems with filterspecs.py which doesn't exist in Django >= 1.4. I will now have to look at how to implement this `list_filter` in 1.3

Answer (score 1):

It was actually the `start_date` field that was causing the problem and I tracked this down to a filter class in the models.py file, with a bit of help from this post:

[django admin custom list_filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740398/django-admin-custom-list-filter)

thanks for the pointers!